# Gain access to users Facebook messenger inbox from Facebook app

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm working on a port of Facebook messenger capable of running on Mobian and a variety of other mobile Linux distributions. I've got the oAuth process working as expected but have hit a wall trying to display a users conversations. According to the following error I need the read_mailbox permission.

```
Reading mailbox messages requires the extended permission read_mailbox
```

Unfortunately this is no longer available, I'm hoping somebody could suggest an alternative/newer permission which would achieve the same purpose as I've not been able to find one so far.

I'm using restfb to make the HTTP request to endpoint "me/conversations" with the following code

```
Connection<Conversation> conversations = client.fetchConnection("me/conversations", Conversation.class);
```

Thanks in advance, all.

Comment: Have you checked out the current docs? https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v9.0/message

Comment: There is no API.

Comment: @scrappedcola I had a good read but the closest thing I could see was the pages_messaging permission which, as far as I can tell, wouldn't work.

Comment: @WizKid Are you saying the endpoint no longer exists? I would have assumed the error response would indicate otherwise. Will update question with some sample code of the request.

Comment: Facebook reduced the access to the user endpoints from version to version. Accessing the user conversations is no longer possible.